# moveit function stop can not work rightly

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,everyone, i am trying to stop the moving trajectory of robot arm in the rviz, and im using function asyncmove()and function stop(),but it is not work. The rviz can receive stop command, but robot continue to move. and i found if i push plan and execute button on the motion_planning_plugin in rviz, and use stop function i wrote, it works successfully. however, when i use function  asyncmove(), it can not stop. Why? And How can i fix it?
these are my src and scripts(i also try python)

```
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan my_plan;  
moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode success = group.plan(my_plan)  
group.asyncexecute(my_plan);  
sleep(1);  
group.stop();  
sleep(1);

plan=arm.plan()  
arm.execute(plan,wait=False)  
rospy.loginfo("move home finished")  
rospy.sleep(0.5)  
arm.stop()  
rospy.loginfo("stoped")  
rospy.sleep(0.5)  
moveit_commander.roscpp_shutdown()
```

Thank you！

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345116/moveit-function-stop-can-not-work-rightly/) by [pikachu](https://answers.ros.org/users/52084/pikachu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-02-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-02-26**:
Where does this code break? What happens if you increase the sleep? Can you make a minimal example where switching `execute` and `asyncExecute` causes the problem to happen?

**Comment by [pikachu](https://answers.ros.org/users/52084/pikachu/) on 2020-02-26**:
[image: image description]

Hello everyone, this  is information of rviz, and i think this means rviz receives stop message but doesn't stop.

**Comment by [pikachu](https://answers.ros.org/users/52084/pikachu/) on 2020-02-26**:
Hello! This code has no error and can run. But arm robot  in rviz just doesn't stop. I have tried lots of sleep time, but they are all same. if i used execute rather than asyncexecute, arm robot would finish excuting and then  stop, which dose not suits my need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone! i have sloved this problem. the code is right and has nothing rong. The problem is that i used wrong controller called arbotix. with ros_controller, the code can work normally.

---

Originally posted by [pikachu](https://answers.ros.org/users/52084/pikachu/) with karma: 16 on 2020-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0